# How can I offer another interface IPv6 addresses?

Tags: networking, dhcp, ipv6, router

I have two networks and their structures are as follows:

```
(network A) ISP router --- (eth1) - Raspberry Pi - (eth0) --- other devices like PC, smartphone, etc. (network B)
```

I want to assign IPv6 addresses to network B, but I have no idea how to achieve this.

Here's a list of IPv6 addresses on my Raspberry Pi:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 fe80::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2400:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 scope global deprecated dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute
       valid_lft 21664sec preferred_lft 0sec
    inet6 fe80::XXXX:XXXX:XXXX:XXXX/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

IPv6 has already been assigned to eth1, and I want to offer another one to eth0 and other devices as well.

What should I use? Dnsmasq, odhcpd, radvd, or wide-dhcpv6-client? I have no clue. So, I would be grateful if you could teach me in a way that's easier to understand.

By the way, I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS installed on my Raspberry Pi.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using, it matters.

Comment: @David I have Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS installed on my Raspberry Pi.